# Android: Theme changes on Alert and AlertDialog depending on the Android version

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, material-components-android, material-components

We have different looks on alert dialogs and dialogs depending on the version.

At styles.xml we have the below

```
<style name="Theme.AppSomething" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppSomething.Alert</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppSomething.Alert</item>

    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Theme.Dialog</item>
```

All AlertDialogs are imported on the code like this

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
```

Now, removing the `android:alertDialogTheme` works great for Android 8 (window width and buttons), but buttons for Android 5 get messed up.

Removing `alertDialogTheme` at Android 5 the buttons are fine but window width is small. At Android 8 width is small again, but buttons are stuck together.

The problem is I cannot understand why it depends on the os version, which of the two should i keep, or how we should modify the app to have some consistency.

EDIT. There is no   values-v##/   styles.xml folder

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use the `AlertDialog` with the `Theme.MaterialComponents` is to use the `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` class:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this,)
            .setTitle("Dialog")
            ...
            .show();
```

and the `materialAlertDialogTheme` attribute in your theme.

```
<style name="Theme.AppSomething" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
</style>
```